# Python で配列を merge する方法

Tags: python, numpy

累積和に基づく順序でリストを結合したいのですが良い方法はありませんか？

```
list_a = [0.39379078 0.43637504 0.08379634 0.05934067 0.02669717]
list_b = [0.39313739 0.4365064  0.08538897 0.05935853 0.02560871]
list_c = [0.3764537  0.45625286 0.09896868 0.05325728 0.01506747]
list_d = [0.16715008 0.20869567 0.34901068 0.10892968 0.09896519 0.05218175 0.01506694]

cumsum_list_a = [0.39379078 0.83016582 0.91396216 0.97330283 1.        ]
cumsum_list_b = [0.39313739 0.82964379 0.91503275 0.97439129 1.        ]
cumsum_list_c = [0.3764537  0.83270656 0.93167524 0.98493253 1.        ]
cumsum_list_d = [0.16715008 0.37584575 0.72485644 0.83378612 0.9327513  0.98493306 1.        ]
```

Comment: 「累積和に基づく順序でリストを結合」の結果は何でしょうか？

Comment: `cumsum_list_a`から`cumsum_list_d`までの四つのリストの中で最小は`cumsum_list_d[0]`の`0.16715008`，二番目に大きいのは`cumsum_list_c[0]`の`0.3764537`で大きい方は`1. 1. 1. 1. `ですよね．この順序に並び替えた`[0.16715008  0.3764537  ......  0.05934067  0.05935853  0.05325728  0.05218175]`が欲しいリストです．割合を区切る値のリストが欲しいので最後の`1.  1.  1.  1.  `に対応する値は要りません．2つのリストを統合できれば十分です．

Comment: `np.sort(np.append(cumsum_list_a, cumsum_list_b))`は`[0.39313739 0.39379078 0.82964379 0.83016582 0.91396216 0.91503275 0.97330283 0.97439129 1 1]`なので，これと同じ編集を`list_a`と`list_b`にした`[0.39313739 0.39379078 0.4365064 0.43637504 0.08379634 0.08538897 0.05934067 0.05935853]`が欲しいリストです．

Comment: 質問は後からでも編集できるので、質問に関わる情報はコメント欄ではなく質問に追記してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました．

```
import numpy as np

list_a = np.array([0.39379078, 0.43637504, 0.08379634, 0.05934067, 0.02669717])
list_b = np.array([0.39313739, 0.4365064, 0.08538897, 0.05935853, 0.02560871])

tmp_list = np.sort(np.append(np.cumsum(list_a), np.cumsum(list_b)))
dest_list = []
for i in range(len(tmp_list) - 1):
    dest_list.append(tmp_list[i + 1] - tmp_list[i])
    
print(dest_list)
```

で`[0.0006533900000000314, 0.43585301, 0.0005220299999999511, 0.08379634000000002, 0.0010706000000000326, 0.05827006999999995, 0.0010884600000000688, 0.02560870999999998, 0.0]`が得られました．
元々の目的が「小さすぎる間隔の削除」にあるのと，2つ以上のリストを扱えるので自己解決としました．
総和は正規化して解決しようと思います．
ありがとうございました！

Comment: 差分はこの計算でも可能です`tmp_list[1:] -tmp_list[:-1]` (あるいはリストにするなら `dest_list = (tmp_list[1:] -tmp_list[:-1]).tolist()`